# Python Regex Scrape & Replace String

Tags: python, regex, replace, beautifulsoup

Hi i would like to code me a small helper Tool in Python it should process the following content:

```
<tr>
 <td><p>L1</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.000x2.300x500;   4,6m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.221 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L2</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.250x2.300x500;   4,9m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.279 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L3</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.500x2.300x500;   5,2m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.321 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L4</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.750x2.300x500;   5,5m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.364 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
```

It should replace the `&nbsp;` of each table row with the the volume in this case everthing between the ; and the ) in the second table data field of each row.

i started to code it in python like that and i could allready scrape the Volume with a regex statement but my logic ends on how to put the values on the right place. any idea ? here is my code

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('3mmcontainer.html') as f:
    content = f.read()
f.close()

#print content

contentsoup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content)

for tablerow in contentsoup.findAll('tr'):
    inhalt = str(tablerow.contents[3])
    print inhalt


    match = re.findall('\;(.*?)\)', inhalt)


    print match
# for x in match:
#    volumen = x.lstrip()
#    print volumen

   #f = open('3mmcontainer.html', 'w')
   #newdata = f.replace("&nbsp;", volumen)
   #f.write(newdata)
   #f.close()


#m = re.search('\;(.*?)\)', inhalt)
# print m

# volumen = re.compile(r'\;(.*?)\)')
# volumen.match(tablerow.contents[3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NB: you don't need to call `close()` because the `with` statement will do it for you.*

You can use a simple function to transform each row (`<tr/>`):

```
import re


def parse_inhalt(content):
    td_list = re.findall(r"<td>(?:(?!</td>).)+</td>", content)
    vol_content = td_list[1]
    vol = re.findall(r";([^)]+)", vol_content)[0]
    return content.replace("&nbsp;", vol)
```

The code is straightforward:

- Extract each cell in `td_list`
- Get the content of the second cell which contains the volume
- Find the *volume* contained between ";" and ")" (excluding those characters)
- Replace the `&nbsp;` by the *volume*

For instance:

```
inhalt = u"""\
<tr>
<td><p>L4</p></td>
<td><p>(4.750x2.300x500;   5,5m³)</p></td>
<td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
<td><p> 1.364 kg</p></td>
</tr>"""

print(parse_inhalt(inhalt))
```

You get:

```
<tr>
<td><p>L4</p></td>
<td><p>(4.750x2.300x500;   5,5m³)</p></td>
<td><p>   5,5m³</p></td>
<td><p> 1.364 kg</p></td>
</tr>
```

You can drop the spaces by using:

```
vol = re.findall(r";\s*([^)]+)", vol_content)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach.

First, find all of the table cells, and the `p` elements within them. You know that the `p` elements are characterised by the presence of *m³* within their `text`s, so watch for them, and you know that you must change the `p` elements that follow immediately. Then arrange to capture the area when you encounter it, note the ordinal number of the `p` element and then when  you encounter the next `p` element, change its `text` by assigning `area` to its `string` attribute.

If you prefer regex then you could use this for calculating `area`:

```
area = bs4.re.search(r';\s+([^\)]+)', p.text).groups(0)[0]
```

.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> k = None
>>> for i, p in enumerate(soup.select('td > p')):
...     if 'm³' in p.text:
...         area = p.text[1+p.text.rfind(';'):-1].strip()
...         k = i
...     if k and i == k + 1:
...         p.string = area
... 
>>> soup
<html><body><tr>
<td><p>L1</p></td>
<td><p>(4.000x2.300x500;   4,6m³)</p></td>
<td><p>4,6m³</p></td>
<td><p> 1.221 kg</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>L2</p></td>
<td><p>(4.250x2.300x500;   4,9m³)</p></td>
<td><p>4,9m³</p></td>
<td><p> 1.279 kg</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>L3</p></td>
<td><p>(4.500x2.300x500;   5,2m³)</p></td>
<td><p>5,2m³</p></td>
<td><p> 1.321 kg</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>L4</p></td>
<td><p>(4.750x2.300x500;   5,5m³)</p></td>
<td><p>5,5m³</p></td>
<td><p> 1.364 kg</p></td>
</tr></body></html>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

if brute force regex is acceptable

```
s='''
<tr>
 <td><p>L1</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.000x2.300x500;   4,6m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.221 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L2</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.250x2.300x500;   4,9m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.279 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L3</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.500x2.300x500;   5,2m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.321 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>L4</p></td>
 <td><p>(4.750x2.300x500;   5,5m³)</p></td>
 <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
 <td><p> 1.364 kg</p></td>
 </tr>
'''

import re

p=r'(\([0-9x.]+)(; +)([0-9,m³]+)(\)</p></td>\n <td><p>)(&nbsp;)'

# not sure which output is preferred
x = re.sub(p, '\g<1>\g<2>\g<3>\g<4>\g<3>', s)
print(x)

y = re.sub(p, '\g<1>\g<4>\g<3>', s)
print(y)
```